# Get the value for a specific key from any type in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am currently using the variable type map(string) as below to declare the email address values of list type. This works fine. however I prefer using map(string,list) type instead of map(string,string).

```
variable "email_addresses" {
  type        = map(string)
  default = {
    team1    = "test1@abc.com,test2@abc.com"
    team2    = "test3@abc.com,test4@abc.com"
}

data "template_file" "policies" {
  for_each = local.policies
  template = file(format("${path.module}/policies/%s.yaml", each.key))
  vars = {
    recipients             = lookup(var.email_addresses, element(split("-", each.key), 0), "")
    tag                    = local.tags["name"]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the value(ie recipients) for a key by the setting the variable to any type as below.

```
variable "email_addresses" {
  type        = any
  default = {
    team1 = [
      "test1@abc.com",
      "test2@abc.com"
    ], 
    team2 = [
     "test3@abc.com",
     "test4@abc.com"
    ], 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refine your variable declaration type in the following way:

```
variable "email_addresses" {
  type        = map(list(string))
  default = {
    team1 = [
      "test1@abc.com",
      "test2@abc.com"
    ], 
    team2 = [
     "test3@abc.com",
     "test4@abc.com"
    ], 
  }
}
```

Then, you can ensure your array of recipients is formatted correctly in your YAML file with the [yamlencode function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/yamlencode.html).

```
data "template_file" "policies" {
  for_each = var.email_addresses
  template = file(format("${path.module}/policies/%s.yaml", each.key))
  vars = {
    recipients             = each.value
    tag                    = local.tags["name"]
  }
}
```

and in your template:

```
---
${yamlencode(recipients)}
```

Note a couple of usage warnings for your config is that `lookup` should only be used when you want to provide a default value if no key exists, and that the `template_file` data should be updated with the [templatefile function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html).